# Printing this array in C

Tags: c, arrays, printing, scanf

I am storing strings from a text file into two different arrays. An example of one line of the text file would look like

> (word);(word2)

Word is being stored into eng[] and word2 would be stored into pir[].

```
i = 0;
int currentChar;
while( currentChar != EOF ) {   
    fscanf(inFile, "%[^;]; %[^\n]", eng[i], pir[i]);

    printf("%s ", pir[i]);
    currentChar = fgetc( inFile );

    i++;

}
```

If I do a loop to print out all the elements inside eng[], I will get everything inside printed out.

```
 printf("%s ", eng[i]);
```

But when trying to print out the pir array, I do not get the same thing. In order to get each element printed out, I need to do

```
 printf("%s\n", pir[i]);
```

But then it prints each element on a separate line, when I want it all on one line.

I'm unsure why it is doing this (I'm new to C). Why is this happening and what can I do to make it print out on one line?

Comment: try `printf("%s ", pir[i]);fflush(stdout);`

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%s\n", pir[i]);` must be `printf("%s", pir[i]);`